# How can I modify my code in order to output the same text that was input before encryption, after decryption?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, encryption

I have written a code for Encryption and Decryption (without any use of key) and I want that after decryption of the message, the message that was input in the time of encryption should be printed as it is.

According to what I did, I am successfully able to get the message after the decryption algorithm is run but the result is not in the order I supplied it when giving the input. It means that: 'h' gets converted to 'H' and same is the case with other letters.

```
# Encryption
# Trial 4

in_text = input('Enter the text that you want to encrypt: ').lower()
out_text = []
for i in in_text:
    if i == ' ':
        out_text.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in 'aeiou':
        out_text.append(ord(i) + 4)
        continue
    else:
        out_text.append(i)
final = ''.join(str(e) for e in out_text)
print(final)

# Decryption
# Trial 2

import string

user_input = input('Enter the text that you want to decrypt: ')
d_out = []
z = ''
for i in user_input:
    if i == ' ':
        d_out.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
        d_out.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in string.digits:
        z = z + i
        n = len(z)
        if n == 3:
            d_out.append(chr(int(z) - 4))
            z = ''

my_str = ''
for a in d_out:
    my_str = my_str + a

print(f'The decrypted message is: {my_str.title()}')
```

When I remove ".lower()" in my Encryption code and ".title()" in my Decryption code, the result differs after decryption and there are some special characters that are printed.

Please let me know on how can I proceed with the same.

Your response will be highly appreciated!

## Case 1

## ENCRYPTION

Enter the text that you want to encrypt: hello World
h105ll115 w115rld

## DECRYPTION

Enter the text that you want to decrypt: h105ll115 w115rld
The decrypted message is: Hello World

## Case 2

## After removing ".lower()" and ".title()"

Making the encryption code to be as follows:

```
in_text = input('Enter the text that you want to encrypt: ')
out_text = []
for i in in_text:
    if i == ' ':
        out_text.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        out_text.append(ord(i) + 4)
        continue
    else:
        out_text.append(i)
final = ''.join(str(e) for e in out_text)
print(final)
```

Making the decryption code as follows:

```
import string

user_input = input('Enter the text that you want to decrypt: ')
d_out = []
z = ''
for i in user_input:
    if i == ' ':
        d_out.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
        d_out.append(i)
        continue
    elif i in string.digits:
        z = z + i
        n = len(z)
        if n == 3:
            d_out.append(chr(int(z) - 4))
            z = ''

my_str = ''
for a in d_out:
    my_str = my_str + a

print(f'The decrypted message is: {my_str}')
```

The output comes as follows:

## Encryption

Enter the text that you want to encrypt: Hello world
H105ll115 w115rld

## Decryption

Enter the text that you want to decrypt: H105ll115 w115rld
The decrypted message is: ello world

Case 1 and Case 2 both have different outputs but the problem of 'h' being 'H' or 'W' being 'w' or other characters being the same order still exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues.

First, only your encryption procedure takes upper capitals into account.

Second, you go through your ciphertext character by character during decryption, while your encryption uses `ord` directly. `ord` will generate *multiple* digits per character.

---

These kind of issues can and should be found *using a debugger* rather than StackOverflow. This is not abnormal program execution, the code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do - but that's incorrect.

I'd first take a look at Viginere implementations and take hints from that if you don't know how to perform these kind of encodings.

---

You will have to solve the multi-digit problem in some way or other, otherwise you won't be able to distinguish where each *number* starts or ends if they are next to each other. For instance, you could put the digits in brackets, e.g. `[69]` for the "encryption" of A (hah, interesting position in your ciphertext), and escape brackets like this `[[` and `]]` if you require brackets to be part of the text.

This should be part of the description of your scheme, which you should probably think out *before* you (re-)start to program. Randomly trying stuff is not going to work.